# Sending mouse click on the place where the caret stands with Autohotkey

Tags: autohotkey

I want to send a mouse click on the place where the caret stands in Keynote editor. Is this possible?

I need this feature because Keynote requires the user to click a link with mouse. There is no keyboard shortcut for jumping to a link in Keynote.

Comment: Keynote is exclusive to Mac OS. AutoHotkey is PC only. What operating system and presentation software are you using?

Comment: I mean Keynote from Tranglos software. It is a hierarchical note editor software like Evernote or OneNote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the built-in variables A_CaretX and A_CaretY:

```
Click, %A_CaretX%, %A_CaretY%
```

If you mean the mouse cursor instead of the keyboard caret, you would use this:

```
MouseGetPos, xpos, ypos
Click, %xpos%, %ypos%
```

There is also ControlClick to send a mouseclick to a specific control (button, field etc.) but you probably don't need that.